# How to apply properties to two divs in CSS

Tags: html, css

Ok, so obviously I know how but for some reason this code is not doing it.

I need the left and right div to have an inset box shadow.

```css
* {
  Margin: 0;
  Padding: 0;
}

.Wrapper {
  Position: Fixed;
  Background: RGB(128,128,128);
  Width: 1500PX;
  Height: 500PX;
  Top: Calc(50% - 250PX);
  Right: Calc(50% - 750PX);
}

.Left, .Center, .Right {
  Display: Inline-Block;
  Width: 500PX;
  Height: 500PX;
}

.Left, .Right {
  Box-Shadow: Inset 0 0 0 50PX RGB(256,256,256);
}
```

```html
<DIV CLASS="Wrapper">
  <DIV CLASS="Left"></DIV>
  <DIV CLASS="Center"></DIV>
  <DIV CLASS="Right"></DIV>
</DIV>
```

Comment: box-shadow is applied to both divs, as i can see...

Comment: I can't see that it is here is the codepen http://codepen.io/Alanay/pen/aBeNjZ

Comment: I can see it here in fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6ra0aow1/ - your right div is pushed down...(on smaller screens)

Comment: Thank you! I'll just use Transform: Translate(,);

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned you should really get away from Capitalizing and maybe consider using a class shadow if you plan on using it on more than just 1 div.

```css
        div { width:100px; height:100px}
        .shadow { box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000; }
```

```html
        <DIV CLASS="Wrapper">
          <DIV CLASS="Left shadow">left</DIV>
          <DIV CLASS="Center">center</DIV>
          <DIV CLASS="Right shadow">right</DIV>
        </DIV>
```